# SAS: Filtering out rows by prevalence and abundance

Tags: sas

I was writing to request help with finding an equivalent way to do something I know how to do in R but have to do in SAS now because of software restrictions.

I have unique samples in columns and features (in my case, bacterial names) in rows. As some have pointed out, I know this is an uncommon data structure.

I would like to eliminate any feature from my table that does not meet my quality control filtering criteria, in this case, a cell value of at least 0.01% and found in at least 10% of the samples:

To do this in R would be the following:

## abundance/prevalence filter

```
spp.filt <- spp.dat[ apply(spp.dat, 1, function(bug) sum(bug >= 0.01) >= 0.1*ncol(spp.dat)), ]
```

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done in SAS?

I was unable to find any relevant results for "filter prevalence" or "filter abundance" but would greatly appreciate any help.

As suggested by others, here is what the data looks like:

```
           sample 1 sample 2    sample 3 
feature a   0        0           0.1
feature b   0       0.2           0
feature c   0        0            0
feature d   0.4      0           0.5
```

Comment: I will note in addition to the answer and the suggestion to include code/sample data, you should consider data structure modifications.  SAS is not a matrix language, and so your data structure may not be appropriate for what you're doing.  SAS is more akin to a relational database - in fact you can pretty much just think of it as a SQL database and be not wrong in most areas, just it's more powerful in certain places (particularly in statistics of course) but not as optimized.  So your column/row arrangement may not be a good one for SAS, again depending on exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Typically you'd have samples in rows, and characteristics of those samples in columns - it sounds like you have the inverse of that.  This may turn out to be useful for you, but odds are it will be more of a pain having it structured this way.  I see a `PROC TRANSPOSE` in your future.

Comment: Sample data would help explain your problem. Typically a matrix can be stored into a dataset by having one variable to identify the row, one to indentify the column and one for the actual measure. You mentioned that you have SampleID and Bacteria, but what is your actual measure?

Comment: Here's some examples of calculating a value and adding it back to your original data set. https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/add_average_value_to_dataset.sas

Comment: I will point out one issue, you're using subject specific jargon rather than generic programming terminology. You'll likely reach more people with programming specific language than with the subject specific jargon.  Basically, simplify your problem to a mathematical/pseudocode step. This way anyone who programs in SAS can help, otherwise you need someone who's familiar with your specific topic area, which is a much smaller pool of users.

Comment: Hi Joe and Tom. I hope my edits clarified things. Thanks Reeza. I found that answer with the github link to be a little general. At your suggestion, I eliminated some of the jargon.

Comment: @Long Again - reshape your data.  Like Reeza said, make it 3 columns, "feature", "sample", "value".  Above would have 12 rows (4x3) 3 columns.  Then it's easy to use SQL or similar to filter things by groupings.

Comment: What is the meaning of the values 0, 0.4 , etc? What name would you give that variable?

Comment: Hi Joe, Would you be willing to clarify what you mean by 3 columns? Hi Tom, sorry for keeping it too general. Within sample 1, features a-d are proportions, is 0.4 is 40%. Not listed are the many other features but their sum should be 1 within each sample.

Answer (score 0):

The way you'd do this in SAS would be simply to use the PROC of your choice to calculate the various numbers you're looking at, and then through one of various methods you'd combine it back in with the main dataset and filter.

So for example if you wanted a list of people in a class who were age 14 or higher, you'd do something like this:

```
proc sql;
  select name into :14oroverlist separated by ' '
  from sashelp.class where age ge 14 ;
quit;

data class;
  set sashelp.class;
  where name in (&14oroverlist.);
run;
```

There're a bunch of other ways to do this, including rolling your own function, that just depend on exactly the details of your program/data/style/preferences.  If you include sample data and desired output you might get something more useful.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I tried to include sample data in my edited response. AS for the desired output, the original table would have many features/rows (>70,000) but the desired output would have significantly fewer after eliminating features that are both not abundant and not that prevalent. Thank you everyone for your help.